# Have a python file move itself

Tags: python

I'm writing a script that emulates a unix environment with python (yes, I know that may sound silly).

Basically I set up the "pwd" and "ls" commands before the "cd" command. Now I need my python script to navigate itself around directories by moving itself. I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction? eg.What commands to use, etc

Note. I would prefer it if I only had to use built-in modules.

Thank You!

Comment: Why would it need to move the script itself? You can change the current working directory with [`os.chdir()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chdir).

Comment: You might be interested in the `cmd` module, which allows your Python program to have an interactive prompt.  Combined with moving the working directory, it could give you the features you want.  http://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html

Comment: This approach might not work as well as you hope... If you want to create a unix like prompt, I think you'll need to write your own shell.  (possible with the `cmd` module austin mentioned) The `cd` command is a builtin command of the shell which makes the shell change its cwd.  If you try to have your python script copy its self about the FS, you could very easily move yourself outside your $PATH.  What happens when it crashes?  You'll have to search the FS for your script. etc etc

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "move itself" or why you want to do this.  Your question could be clearer

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize os.chdir() even existed. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand you properly, but if you are talking about moving through the standard unix file system and not copying the script to different locations, you could easily just wrap the three commands (pwd,ls,cd) as python functions, just as you were describing.

In fact, I did this as part of the wx_py project; they aren't perfect clones, but they work well enough. Here are the three functions:

```
import os
import glob

def pwd():
    print os.getcwd()

def cd(path,usePrint=True):
    os.chdir(os.path.expandvars(os.path.expanduser(path)))
    if usePrint:
        pwd()

def ls(str='*',fullpath=False):
    g=glob.glob(os.path.expandvars(os.path.expanduser(str)))
    if fullpath:
        for i in g:
            print i
    else:
        for i in g:
            print os.path.split(i)[1]
```

The full file is at:

https://github.com/davidmashburn/wx_py/blob/master/wx_py/path.py

I'm sure others may have done a better job, so please just take these functions as a starting point.